# BY processing in PROC NLMIXED; procedure stops due to error

Tags: sas, simulation

I simulated 500 replications and planned to analyze each in NLMIXED using BY processing. My NLMIXED code is below:

```
PROC NLMIXED DATA=MELS GCONV=1E-12 QPOINTS=11;
    BY Rep;
    PARMS LMFI=&LMFI.
          SMFI=&SMFI.
          LMRIvar=&LMRIvar. 
          SMRIvar=0 TO 0.15 BY 0.005; 
    mu = LMFI + b0i;
    evar = EXP(SMFI + t0i);
    MODEL Y ~ NORMAL(mu,evar);
    RANDOM b0i t0i ~ NORMAL([0,0],[LMRIvar,0,SMRIvar]) SUBJECT=PersonID;
    ODS OUTPUT FitStatistics=Fit2 ConvergenceStatus=Conv2 ParameterEstimates=Parm2;
RUN;
```

For some of these replications, the variance components were sampled to be small, so some non-zero number of convergence errors are expected (note the ConvergenceStatus request on the ODS OUTPUT statement). However, when I get the warning below, NLMIXED quits processing regardless of the number of replications remaining to be analyzed.

```
WARNING: The final Hessian matrix is full rank but has at least one negative eigenvalue. Second-order optimality condition violated.
ERROR: QUANEW Optimization cannot be completed.
```

Am I missing something? I would think that NLMIXED could acknowledge the error for that replication, but continue with the remaining replications. Thoughts are appreciated!

Best,
Ryan

Comment: As far as I can see, the syntax looks solid. This sounds a lot like data problem. As the error states, the resulting eigenvalue(s) are are negative, which is not allowed. In cases like this, I'd suggest beginning with partial data, simpler model or generated test set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I believe is occurring.  The requirement that variances must be non-negative and the fact that the distribution of variance estimates is long-tailed make variances troublesome to estimate.  Variance component estimate updates may result in a negative value for one or more of the estimates.  The NLMIXED procedure attempts to compute eigenvalues of the model variance components.  At that point, NLMIXED crashes.

But note that

```
V[Y] = (sd[Y])^2
V[Y] = exp(ln(V[Y]))
V[Y] = exp(2*ln(sd[Y]))
V[Y] = exp(2*ln_sd_Y)
```

Now, suppose that we make ln_sd_Y the parameter.  References to V[Y] would need to be written as the function shown in the last statement above.  As the domain of the parameter ln_sd_Y is (-infinity, infinity), there is no lower bound on ln_sd_Y.  The function exp(2*ln_sd_Y) will always produce a non-negative variance estimate.  Actually, given limitations of digital computers such that negative infinity cannot be represented, only values which head to negative infinity), the function exp(2*ln_sd_Y) will always produce a positive parameter estimate. The estimate may be very, very close to 0.  But the estimate would always come at 0 from above.  This should preclude SAS trying to compute the eigenvalue of a negative number.

A slight alteration of your code writes LMRIvar and SMRIvar as functions of ln_sd_LMRIvar and ln_sd_SMRIvar.

```
PROC NLMIXED DATA=MELS GCONV=1E-12 QPOINTS=11;
    BY Rep;
    PARMS LMFI=&LMFI.
          SMFI=&SMFI.
          ln_sd_LMRIvar=%sysfunc(log(%sysfunc(sqrt(&LMRIvar.)))) 
          ln_sd_SMRIvar=-5 to -1 by 0.1;
    mu = LMFI + b0i;
    evar = EXP(SMFI + t0i);
    MODEL Y ~ NORMAL(mu,evar);
    RANDOM b0i t0i ~ NORMAL([0,0],
                            [exp(2*ln_sd_LMRIvar), 0,
                               exp(2*ln_sd_SMRIvar)]) SUBJECT=PersonID;
    ODS OUTPUT FitStatistics=Fit2 ConvergenceStatus=Conv2 ParameterEstimates=Parm2;
RUN;
```

Alternatively, you could employ a bounds statement in an attempt to prevent updates of LMRIvar and/or SMRIvar from going negative.  You could keep your original code, inserting the statement

```
bounds LMRIvar SMRIvar > 0;
```

This is simpler than writing the model in terms of parameters which are allowed to go negative.  However, my experience has been that employing parameters which have domain (-infinity, infinity) is actually the better approach.